# React Formik yup validation test not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

React Formik yup validation  with Api for Email already exist the function using test yup but they affect all field validation. If I use the that function all other validation are not working I am validate on blur .please help me

code sandbox link :https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-brahmagupta-4gyrj?file=/src/App.js